# How to save the content of a MOC to a file, with no -wal and no -shm?

Tags: sqlite, cocoa, core-data, wal

I want to save the content of a `MOC` to a file `myFile.ext`. Everything works well, my data is saved to the file BUT I have to auxiliary files in addition:

- `myFile.ext-wal`
- `myFile.ext-shm`

Are these files necessary for my purpose (saving the content of a `MOC` to a file)? I would like to "ship" my data in only one file. Furthermore, when I get again my data, I only use the `URL` of `myFile.ext`.

If they are not necessary, is it possible to avoid their creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As CL indicated they are necessary in WAL mode.  To disable the journaling mode when creating your persistent store pass the flowing option.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"DELETE"};

_coordinator = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:options error:&storeError];
```

When you run your app again the -wal should disappear and the -shm can be deleted or ignored.  All you data should be in the one sqlite file.

Comment: Yes, I found [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) also.

Answer (score 2):

These files are created (and are necessary) when the database is in [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

To disable WAL mode, open the database directly and execute [PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode).

Comment: I don't know about you, but even with `journal_mode = DELETE", core data sometimes creates WAL & SHM files. Anybody found a solution to that?